# If all vectors in a set are perpendicular to a given vector, is the set linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If it is known that all vectors in a set are perpendicular to some nonzero vector $\textbf{w}$, is that sufficient to show that the set is linearly dependent? Is it a necessary condition as well?

In two dimensions it seems obvious, because having two parallel vectors is equivalent to the existence of a vector perpendicular to both. I can't see any obvious reason why it would work with three dimensions.

Comment: Hmmm, I should have specified that I was considering three vectors over three dimensions, or two vectors over two dimensions. Not sure whether I should edit the question or pose a new one. (Although my reason for suspecting it to be true is now looking dubious, so perhaps I should just ask for a counterexample to the conjecture.)

Comment: Maybe you meant to ask whether or not given $n$ vectors in $n$-space orthogonal to a vector $v$, the set of $n$ vectors must be linearly dependent.  The answer is yes, unless $v=0$.  This is because if the $n$ vectors are linearly independent they span $n$-space and so $v$ is a linear combination.  Then take the inner product of $v$ with itself, which is zero since the $n$ vectors are all orthogonal to $v$.  Hence $v$ is zero since it's inner product with iself is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, of course not.  In 3 dimensions you can have two linearly independent vectors in a plane, which are both perpendicular to the normal of the plane.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be nonzero vectors.

Set $w = u \times v$. The vector $w$ is of course orthogonal, or perpendicular, to both $u$ and $v$, as is $2w$ and $3w$.

Consider the set $\{w,2w,3w\}$; each element of this set is perpendicular to the nonzero vector $v$ (and $u$) but the set is not linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the set $\{(0,1)\}$ has all vectors perpendicular to $(1,0)$, but it's not linearly dependent. Also, the empty set poses a problem. Or, the set of vectors $\{(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ or, generally, $\{(0,1,0,0,\ldots),(0,0,1,0,\ldots),(0,0,0,1,\ldots),\ldots\}$.

The problem is that you could take any vector space add a new, perpendicular dimension - so it's meaningless to consider whether such a vector exists.